# How to get Qhull PyHull on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: ros, mac

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing ROS on Mac (I know, its unsupported, but I have to try). The instructions are really good and complete for something this complex, I have to say. And yet there are a few hiccups. Can someone help me solve this error?

```
cd /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes && /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometric_shapes -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/geometric_shapes -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
```

Gives this output and stops the build:

```
cd /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes && /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/env.sh cmake /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/src/geometric_shapes -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/geometric_shapes -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G 'Unix Makefiles'
-- Boost version: 1.64.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   filesystem
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/geometric_shapes
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- This workspace overlays: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/em.pyc
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes/test_results
-- Found gtest: gtests will be built
-- nosetests not found, Python tests can not be run (try installing package 'python-nose')
-- catkin 0.7.6
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.9.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Qhull (missing: QHULL_LIBRARY QHULL_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.9.0/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:377 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/FindQhull.cmake:65 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:51 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/pitosalas/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/geometric_shapes/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
bash-3.2$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266873/how-to-get-qhull-pyhull-on-mac-os-sierra/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2017-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried to install qhull manually?

```
brew install qhull
```

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/2823

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2017-07-20**:
For some reason I had tried it and it didn't work, but I must have mistyped, because now it did work.